# Ubuntu 23.04 invisible mouse

Tags: mouse, kde, cursor, 23.04

***System I use***

> I use Ubuntu 23.04 desktop and KDE.

***Symptom***

> The mouse cursor disappears.

***Circumstances***

> If I move the mouse I cannot see the mouse cursor itself but left
> click, right click and so are still work.
>
> It happens often. No time or habit dependency. Sometimes it happens
> after 2 minutes sometimes after 15 minutes. Sometimes Remmina is
> opened sometimes only the Firefox runs.

***Hardware relation***

> This instance of Ubuntu runs on an old imac (i even don't know its
> serie).

***Possible clues in any log***

> I did check the log by using `dmesg` but tbh I don't know what I
> suppose to look for.

*Any help is appreciated.*

Comment: If this is occurring over specific windows, what windows are they (ie. it maybe a pattern, eg. GTK, or *snap* windows but not Qt5/KDE for example; you may not know the toolkit/library like I'm referring to here, but what *apps* are they & provide whatever level of detail you can)..  You mention KDE on 23.04; so is this a Kubuntu 23.04 install? or you've added specific packages & have only parts of Kubuntu/KDE Plasma?

Comment: This is Ubuntu and I installed KDE by using this command: `sudo apt install kde-plasma-desktop ` Instructions came from here: https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-kde-desktop-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

(I don't understand what the following code does but it solves the root issue.)

Mouse cursor doesn't disappear if I apply the following solution.

**If** `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/swcursor.conf` doesn't exist **then** create it first (execute the following lines):

`su -`

```
mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ &&  touch /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/swcursor.conf &&  echo 'Section "Device"' >> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/swcursor.conf &&  echo 'Identifier "Device0"' >> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/swcursor.conf &&  echo 'Driver "intel"' >> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/swcursor.conf &&  echo 'Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"' >> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/swcursor.conf &&  echo 'Option "SWCursor" "on"' >> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/swcursor.conf &&  echo 'EndSection' >> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/swcursor.conf
```

Check the file if exists.

1.) Log out.
2.) Log in.

The key is: `uxa acceleration`

**Possible side effect:**

The cursor is anxiously blinking/repositioning.